# Adding new column using Update-Database in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

May be i'm missing something very obvious. But i haven't been able to figure out a way to add a new column to an existing table/model in EF Core.

This is the documentation that I'm following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell

And this is what i have done so far:

1. Created migration using this command: "Add-Migration -Name CodingSoldierDbContextMigration -OutputDir Migrations -Context CodingSoldierDbContext"
2. Updated database using the command: "Update-Database -Migration CodingSoldierDbContextMigration -Context CodingSoldierDbContext". Tables got created in the Database.
3. Now i need to add a new column to an existing table. I add that column to the model in the .cs file. And i remove the existing migration: "Remove-Migration -Force -Context CodingSoldierDbContext"
4. Now i re-run the commands in steps 1 and 2. Add-Migration works and migration gets created. But Update-Database fails with the error: "There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database." which means the table is already present in the database which makes sense.

So how do i update an already existing table table ? 
2 ways i can think of are:

1. Drop the database. Create migration and update database. But all data will be gone.
2. Add column in the model. Manually update the Table using a SQL script to add the new column.

But i feel there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: After modifying the model (like adding column), you need to add **new** migration and then run `Update-Database`. Don't do `Remove-Migration`, especially with `-Force` flag - it's for exceptional cases.

Comment: By "new" you mean a migration with new name? If so, I did try that. But was getting the same error. Moreover removing the existing migration and adding it again should be a "new" migration right ?

Comment: Removing it with -Force messes the things up. Normally `Remove-Migration` will ask you to first rollback the migration in the database (i.e. executing the `Down` method commands). The way you did it, the "new" migration tries to do things that are already done in database (like creating table which is already created), hence the exceptions.

Comment: Well for me, "Remove-Migration" didnt ask for any rollback in Database. It just removed the Migration files(.cs) in project. 
And i figured out that the Remove-Migration was causing the next migration to act like it was the initial migration instead of update. 
Anyways thanks for your help @IvanStoev

Answer (score 7):

This is how i resolved the issue. Not sure if it is the perfect way.

Key is NOT to delete the initial migration, before you create the new migration.

Adding the steps here:

1. Creating initial migration: "Add-Migration -Name CodingSoldierDbContextMigration -OutputDir Migrations -Context CodingSoldierDbContext"
2. Updated database using the command: "Update-Database -Migration CodingSoldierDbContextMigration -Context CodingSoldierDbContext". Tables gets created in the Database.
3. Added new field in one of the models.
4. Creating updated migration: "Add-Migration -Name CodingSoldierDbContextMigrationUpdated -OutputDir Migrations -Context CodingSoldierDbContext". This migration will have code only for updating the existing table.
5. Updating DB with the updated migration: "Update-Database -Migration CodingSoldierDbContextMigrationUpdated". Ideally this should have resolved it. But for me, it gave error because(as from Verbose logs) it was trying to update with initial migration: "CodingSoldierDbContextMigration", i don't know why.
6. So i generate scripts using Script-Migration: "Script-Migration -From CodingSoldierDbContextMigration -Idempotent -Output C:\MigrationScript.sql -Context CodingSoldierDbContext". It generated the script which had changes only from the updated migration. Running that script in DB created the column and added the migration entry in "__EFMigrationsHistory" table.

Answer (score 4):

I kinda did a mixture of what @Boney and @StepUp suggested and it ran without hitches. Here's what I did. Assume a have a table Period that I decided to add an additional column PeriodTypeId.

1. Add another migration. e.g.

`Add-Migration -Name OVCDbMigrationsUpdated -Context DbContext`

This created a new migration file with name: OVCDbMigrationsUpdated.

2. Run Update-Database targeting the new migration file. e.g.

`Update-Database -verbose -Migration OVCDbMigrationsUpdated -Context DbContext`

My DB was updated successfully with the new column.

Answer (score 3):

This is a way which helped me to add a new column to the existed database without losing data:

1. I've written this command into Package Manager Console to the Project which contains my Model

   ```
   add-migration MyFirstMigration
   ```
2. The above command created a class with a lot of code:

   ```
   public partial class MyFirstMigration : Migration
   {
       protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
       {
             ...
             // The code is omitted for the brevity
             ...
        }
   }
   ```
3. I've deleted all generated code and added the following code snippet into the above method `Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)`:

   ```
   protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
   {
       migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>("Password", "Users", "varchar(255)", 
           unicode:false, maxLength: 255, nullable: true);
   }
   ```
4. Then it is necessary to write the following command into Package Manager Console to add a column into your database:

   ```
   Update-Database
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar issue with EF Core and an existing database with some of the model fleshed out, but I was adding a new model (that already had a table) and was getting the error

```
There is already an object named 'tableN' in the database.
```

The way I got this to work on an existing database was:

1. Download Repo
2. Run all migrations up to date (if you have a database with migrations)
   If you don't, then just create an initial "dummy" migration and apply that
3. Create a baseline migration prior to making any changes in your model/code
4. Update your code with any changes to your database
5. Create another migration
6. Delete the initial baseline migration
7. update-database

Answer (score 0):

Update-Database will work if we exclude previous migration from solution and then run update-database cmd. However we can include again for DB definition.
Directly it won't work in case of EF core + postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

One doesn't need to remove the migration or delete the table. If you want to add a new column to the database table which was already created using add-migration and update-database, one needs to again run the command (add-migration) in nuget package manager console with a new migration name (add-migration "Name2") and then run the command (update-database). The system will know what changes have been made and creates a new migration file but the new column will be added to the same database table where you want to add the column.