# Updating a table with a new column using EF Core 2.0 Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm new to EF Core and have been working through an online course and a book. I created my database context and used `dotnet ef migrations add init` followed by `dotnet ef database update` and all was well much to my delight. I added a new column to my model and created and applied a new migration but was met with:

```
> Applying migration '20180417175820_AddOsTypeColumn'.
Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [MachineTypes] (
    [MachineTypeID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Description] varchar(15) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MachineTypes] PRIMARY KEY ([MachineTypeID])
);
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'MachineTypes' in the database.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInA
ction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrap
CloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectio
nLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, B
ulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean as
yncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, In
t32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbComma
ndMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection,
 IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadO
nlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migration
Commands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String c
ontextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:09aa3af2-6ce8-4331-a586-c79841f4e1b6
Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16
There is already an object named 'MachineTypes' in the database.
```

I looked at this post [Adding new column using update database in entity framework core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46538858/adding-new-column-using-update-database-in-entity-framework-core) which had the same initial problem as mine but the only solution provided didn't really fit my situation; my log indicated that it was applying the correct migration but was then trying to create an existing table as if it was running the init migration.

As it was only a practice/learning database I dropped it from SQL Server and started again. This time, following the steps described above worked as expected. The only difference this time that I was aware of was that I wasn't connected to the database when adding the new column/new migration. Would that have been the cause?

Answer (score 1):

> The only difference this time that I was aware of was that I wasn't connected to the database when adding the new column/new migration. Would that have been the cause?

I think you're mixing up terms here. Adding a new column is an operation on the database; adding a new migration is an operation on your project.

Updating a database without being connected to a database is not possible, so I'm assuming you're talking about changing your model / adding a migration. EF does not look at any database for this, so no.

To clarify (assuming code-first approach)

When you **create** a migration (add migration), EF will look at these two things:

- Your **DbContext class**, to determine the full schema that your database needs to have
- Your **migration classes**, to determine the (delta) schema that needs to be *applied* to your database (and thus the code to be generated for the new migration)

When you **apply** a migration (update database), EF will look at these two things:

- The **migration history table** of your *existing* database (if it exists and has one), to determine which migrations have already been applied
- Your **migration classes**, to see if there are any migrations that have not been applied yet

---

So when you get the error you posted, it means either:

- Your second migration was created without EF taking into account your existing migrations (you changed namespaces in between, pointed to the wrong migrations folder, etc)

  - new migration includes changes from old migrations
- You called update on a database that already had one or more migrations applied to it, but did not have the (correct) migration history

  - same migration gets applied multiple times

Comment: I think I may have found the issue and it would seem related to your second point. I have my project on OneDrive and was trying to recreate the project on my work laptop. I'm guessing that migration classes are specific to a database/project; I had copied the migration files as well thinking they would work. Seems like that isn't the case. When I tried this out at home by only copying the changed classes but recreating the migration, all worked as expected.

Comment: My problem was I changed my namespace, thanks for posting!