# ASP.NET Core Web API with Entity Framework Core 7 code-first: how to get lambda property to migrate into database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

I am building an ASP.NET Core Web API with EF Core 7, and am using a code-first approach. One of my classes has a lambda property `TitleNormalized`, and I want it to appear as a column in my SQL Server table. When I migrate it, the column does not appear (however, it does appear when the `GET` request is serialized via OpenAPI).

This is what my class looks like:

```
[Index(nameof(Title))]
public class Artwork : BaseObject
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string TitleNormalized => StringExtensions.NormalizeString(Title) ?? string.Empty;
}

public class ArtworkEntityTypeConfiguration : BaseObjectTypeConfiguration<Artwork>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Artwork> builder)
    {
        //// Max Length
        builder
            .Property(b => b.Title)
            .HasMaxLength(500);

        base.Configure(builder);
    }
}
```

How should I rewrite this so a column gets created and autopopulated in SQL Server?

Comment: @sicon_corn, have you tried like this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46538858/adding-new-column-using-update-database-in-entity-framework-core

Comment: @RamSingh I'm not sure what I should be focused on in that post. I am able to migrate everything, but the lambda property does not appear as a column in the resulting table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46542182/627885